# Dialogflow deploy JAVA library

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm looking for a way to deploy version in Dialogflow from an external build program(like jenkins or Local server..not Dialogflow console).

But I don't have anything to do it....

Does anyone know how to do the above?